# Dealing with Objects from ElasticSearch - Do I need to reconstruct it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, elasticsearch

So I'm using a library called Reactive which works with Elastic Search to display results and set queries. I'm creating my own custom dropdown list with [ReactiveComponent](https://opensource.appbase.io/advanced/reactivecomponent.html) and when I use a range with a custom label..  meaning, setting `Keyed: true`, ([Reference, take a look at Keyed Response and the response object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation)) I no longer get an array rather I get an object which is making it difficult to display the items I want.

So the response I get looks like:

```
{
  2000 - 2005: { from: 2000, to: 2005, doc_count: 32 }
  2006 - 2010: { from: 2006, to: 2010, doc_count: 77 }
  2011 - 2015: { from: 2011, to: 2015, doc_count: 94 }
  2016 - 2018: { from: 2016, to: 2018, doc_count: 28 }
}
```

But in order to map over and display the necessary values, I'd like for it to look more like

```
[{ key: "2016-2018", from: 2016, to: 2018, doc_count: 28} ] (etc)...
```

Any suggestions on what I should do? Reconstruct the object or go in a different direction?

Comment: Your ReactiveComponent link is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on the ElasticSearch link you provided won't you get exactly what you want if you just don't specify `keyed: true` in the request?

Well, if not then use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
Object.entries(response).map(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key) // "2016-2018"
  console.log(value) // { from: 2016, to: 2018, doc_count: 28 }
})
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. One of the requirements I need is to customize the labels (keys), and the only way to do it is with `keyed: true` . I'm not familiar with Object.entries so I'll give it a shot but I found my solution. I'll post in a sec.

Comment: I can see that the response without `keyed: true` returns keys in an object as you want: `{"key": "2016-2018", "to": 100.0, "doc_count": 2 }`. What stops you to customize labels(keys) with such response?
Sure, your solution with `Object.keys` works the same as mine basically, you just don't need to do extra `results[datum]` to get the value since it's already passed as `value` if using `Object.entries`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const reconstructedResults = [];
      const results = aggregations[searchType].buckets;
      Object.keys(results).map(datum => {
        const datapoint = { key: datum, ...results[datum] };
        results[datum] = datapoint;
        return reconstructedResults.push(results[datum]);
      });
```